# Criar colunas dinâmicas dependendo de uma checkbox - excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabela-html

Eu tenho uma tabela simples com 4 valores e uma checkbox para cada um deles:

Vendedores: |
João |
Antonio |
Paulo |
Carlos

Noutra folha excel, eu tenho uma tabela onde posso adicionar linhas, e onde cada linha tem Mês-Ano. Eu estou querendo que as colunas sejam os vendedores com a checkbox ativa da tabela. Se selecionar João e Paulo, a minha tabela mostrará apenas as vendas para esses dois vendedores. Se retirar a checkbox do João, fica apenas uma coluna. Se colocar checkbox em todos, a minha tabela terá quatro colunas.

Qual é a melhor forma de fazer isto em excel 2007?

Comment: Quais campos você tem? `Vendedor`, `Mês-ano`, ... Daí você quer pegar o vendedor e transformar em coluna?

Comment: Numa tabela tenho só a lista de vendedores.
Na outra tabela eu queria nas linhas mês-ano e nas colunas queria os vendedores que selecionei na primeira tabela.

Comment: E na interseção linhaxcoluna, seria a soma de alguma coisa?

Comment: Não. O excel é para ser preenchido posteriormente de forma manual. A celula deverá ficar em branco.

Comment: O assunto desta pergunta está sendo votado em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/101

Answer (score 1):

Consigo fazer algo similar ao que você pediu, vamos ver se atende.

Supondo a seguinte tabela:

```
+------------+---------+
| Vendedores | Mês-Ano |
+------------+---------+
| João       | jan/14  |
+------------+---------+
| João       | fev/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Antonio    | jan/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Antonio    | fev/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Paulo      | jan/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Paulo      | fev/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Carlos     | jan/14  |
+------------+---------+
| Carlos     | fev/14  |
+------------+---------+
```

Clique na aba Inserir e em seguida clique em Tabela Dinâmica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai abrir uma janela pedindo o intervalos dos dados a ser usado na criação dessa tabela dinâmica, geralmente o próprio Excel já seleciona automaticamente a tabela inteira, se não tiver selecionado marque o intervalo dos dados que deseja usar. Clique em Ok.

Será criado uma nova aba. Arraste o campo vendedor para Rótulos de Coluna e arraste o Mês-Ano para Rótulos de linha, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será criada uma tabela assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba o botão com uma setinha do lado do célula Rótulos de Coluna, se você clicar nela poderá escolher quais vendedores deseja mostrar na tabela dinâmica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para finalizar, após escolhidos os vendedores, copie a tabela e Cole Como Valor em alguma planilha nova, pois a tabela dinâmica é somente leitura.